# Pulling Data With Date Between Two Days using SQLite in Powershell

Tags: sqlite, powershell

currently i'm trying to pull data from dates 9 days ago. The problem i'm currently having is that even tho the query isn't running into errors, i'm still not pulling the data I'm looking for. I'm starting to wonder if it has something to do with the formatting of the date field in the data based.

Here's what the dates look like in the database.

```
2019-07-29 21:17:28.4516886+00:00
2019-07-29 21:25:16.8570866+00:00
2019-07-29 21:25:16.908947+00:00
2019-07-29 21:26:04.9377803+00:00
2019-07-29 21:26:05.2968044+00:00
```

And here is the current code I have for the query, and calling the query to pull it from the database.

```
$Database = "C:\main\main.db"

$query = "SELECT [email], [campaign_id], [status], [modified_date],* FROM [main].[results] WHERE [modified_date] BETWEEN (SELECT DATETIME('now','-8 day')) and (SELECT DATETIME('now','-10 day'));"

$emaildata = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $Database -Query $query  | Select @{Name="EmailAddress";Expression={$_.Email}}, @{Name="Campaign_ID";Expression={$_.campaign_id}} , @{Name="Status";Expression={$_.status}}, @{Name="Date_Modified";Expression={$_.modified_date}}
write-output $emaildata
```

If I do NOT BETWEEN, then it pulls everything, while just BETWEEN pulls nothing.

So i'm hoping to figure out what I need to change to have the dates pulled correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your statement to this:

```
BETWEEN DATETIME('now','-10 day') and DATETIME('now','-8 day')
```

`DATETIME('now','-10 day')` is before `DATETIME('now','-8 day')`.
Also you don't need `SELECT` to get `DATETIME('now','-10 day')`

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but for some reason working with this database it uses some weird formatting. So I always have to change what you'd normally use around quite a bit to not get errors. But thanks! I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: And it totally works, haha I can't believe that it was something so small. Thanks!